# functions.php add_filter append to $path_info['url'] - Gravity Forms

Tags: php, add-filter

I am trying to find a solution to modifying a path info so that the file upload path URL will be an image rather than a url.

```
add_filter( 'gform_upload_path', 'change_upload_path', 10, 2 );
function change_upload_path( $path_info, $form_id ) {
   $path_info['path'] = '/home/public_html/wp-content/uploads/photo_uploads/';
   $path_info['url'] = 'http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/photo_uploads/';
   return $path_info;
}
```

However, the $path_info['url'] needs to be wrapped in an img tag.
Is there a way to append img src=" at the front and a closing tag > after it.

```
$path_info['url'] = append <img src=" in front of the file name 'http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/photo_uploads/' append > to close the tag ;
```

The purpose here is to convert a URL into a img src.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to handle this in two parts. The first is to use the `gform_upload_path` filter to alter the image's upload path. The second is to use the [`gform_entry_field_value`](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_entry_field_value/) filter to wrap the URL in an <img> tag when it is retrieved from the database.

Pretty much anywhere the field value is displayed, the `gform_entry_field_value` filter is called so you'll always have your image-wrapped URL.

Update w/ code:

```
add_filter( 'gform_upload_path', 'change_upload_path', 10, 2 );
function change_upload_path( $path_info, $form_id ) {
   $path_info['path'] = '/home/public_html/wp-content/uploads/photo_uploads/';
   $path_info['url'] = 'http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/photo_uploads/';
   return $path_info;
}

// update "10" to the ID of your form, update "3" to the ID of your field
add_filter( 'gform_entry_field_value', 'convert_to_image', 10, 4 );
function convert_to_image( $value, $field, $entry, $form ) {
    return $field->formId == 1247 && $field->id == 2 ? sprintf( '<img src="%s" />', $entry[ $field->id ] ) : $value;
}
```

Comment: David, thanks for your suggestions. Do you think it's possible to provide an working code?

Comment: David, I appreciate your help. When using the gform_get_input_value, the file upload did not get sent in the GF admin email notification. Strangely, when I used a broken code, it does show up on the GF admin notification email. The below code is missing a closing tag but it does appears on the GF admin notification email as a file upload with the link to the file on the server. (below is a partial of the gform_upload_path code)

    $path_info['url'] = '<img src="http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/photo_uploads/';
    return $path_info;}

Comment: Made another edit. My previous example had some problems.

Comment: David, the revised code works. Thanks for your great skills and kindness. Your help is greatly appreciated. I'd give another point if it's possible.